# Why is the Quasitriangular Hopf algebra called "Quasitriangular"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, terminology, hopf-algebras, quantum-groups

The precise definition of a *Quasitriangular Hopf algebra* can be found on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasitriangular_Hopf_algebra).

What is the reason behind the word "Quasitriangular"?

Is it because the R-matrix  is a triangular matrix, or is it related to some properties of triangles?

Thanks for the enlightenment.

Comment: Reading this paper (http://people.math.harvard.edu/~yfu/drinfeld_on_almost.pdf) by Drinfeld, might give some insight. He calls the Quantum-Yang-Baxter equation $R_{12}R_{13}R_{23}= R_{23}R_{13}R_{12}$ (which is satisfied by the universal $R$ matrix) the *triangular equation*. Other sometimes call it *the star-triangle equation*, I think. I don't know why - maybe others can shine some light on it.